# regarding dojo registry and watch

Tags: events, dojo, registry, watch

I have a piece of code like so, the aim of this code is to print out to console when a value in a.options changes where a is a custom widget. :

```
var a = registry.byId("options");

a.watch("search", function(){
    console.log("registered change");
});
```

var a has a field called search

my understanding of this code is that when a change is seen in search the callback is executed.

Sadly I am not seeing this behaviour

i am using dojo 1.10

Comment: Not much information here.  What widget has the `options` ID?  What meaning does the `search` property supposedly have within that widget?

Comment: the options id is that of a custom widget which handles data that is later used to construct a rest request, the search property is a variable that contains data needed to construct a rest request

Comment: Then we need to see the code of that widget, and what's using it.  Are you calling `set('search', ...)` properly (not just modifying the property directly which has no way to notify watchers)?  Does the widget have a custom `_setSearchAttr` and if so, does it remember to call `this._set('search', ...)` so that watchers are notified?

Comment: it has none of these things, i will report back when i have made these changes#